# Issue with regex matching in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to Perl and any help will be appreciated. I have 2 variables: `$release` and `$env_type`. I want to check if a string contains `$release_$env_type`, then do something. For example,

```
$release="beta";
$env_type="testing";
so string is beta_testing
```

**Code snippet:**

```
if ( $_ =~ /${release}_${env_type}/ ) {
        #do Something
 }
```

This if condition doesn't get resolved. Kindly let me know what is the correct syntax to make this check? I searched on Google but didn't get any good post..

Kindly help!

I have a file with contents:

```
admin_vh_c9_simv2_edg=/console,/consolehelp
idminternal_vh_c9_simv2_edg=/oim,/soa-infra
sso_vh_c9_simv2_edg=/oim,/soa-infra,/odsm

my $env_type = "edg";
my $release  = "c9_simv2";
#Input file containing contexts
my $idmInternal = "./IdmContexts.conf";
if ( !-e $idmInternal ) {
    die "Unable to find the file $idmInternal!\n";
}

open( MYFILE, $idmInternal );
while (<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    if ( $_ =~ /${release}_${env_type}/ ) {
        push( @filtered, $_ );
    }

}
```

Comment: So why not printing `$_` before `if` condition?

Comment: Looks like it should work. Now the questions: what's in `$_` and does it contain "beta_testing"? `use strict;use warnings;` might tell you if `$_` was undefined.

Comment: Unless your variables contain regex meta characters, it is probably safer to escape the variables using `\Q${release}_${env_type}\E` or `quotemeta`.

Comment: Nit: It's not `=~` doing the matching, it's the match operator (`m//` aka `//`).

Comment: Nit#2: The code you have shown works as it should. You have changed it to remove the faulty part(s) (most likely the assignment of `$_` and the two variables) So if you want an accurate solution, you need to describe your problem more accurately. Most likely by posting your original code.

Comment: Side-note: You should get rid of that file-existence check and check errors given by `open` instead (`open( MYFILE, $idmInternal ) or die("Can't open $idmInternal: $!\n");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To really tell what is going on, you can inject code before the test. For example *compile* a regex first and then print it.

```
# compile the regex first
my $regex = qr/${release}_${env_type}/;

say qq{\$regex="$regex"};

# then print your scanned text
say qq{\$_="$_"};

if ( m/$regex/ ) { 
    # do something
}
```

If you're going to explicitly bind to a regex, then use variables:

```
my $string = $_;
if ( $string =~ m/$regex/ ) { 
}
```

Otherwise, simply *match* the "context variable" (`$_`).

```
 if ( m/$regex/ ) { 
 }
```

Also, USUW would help spot a few problems, proactively:

```
# Before everything else
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code is fine. The problem is elsewhere. The following prints `match`.

```
my $release="beta";
my $env_type="testing";

$_ = "so string is beta_testing";

if ( $_ =~ /${release}_${env_type}/ ) {
   print "match\n";
}
```

Note: `/\Q${release}_${env_type}/` would be better. It'll make sure that special characters in the interpolated variables match themselves.

---

Most likely problem: You read the value of `$release` and/or `$env_type` from a file, and forgot to `chomp` the trailing newline.

Comment: I have added the content of my file and my code in the question itself..Its not working..Kindly help what is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `$_` then this will work.

```
if (m/${release}_${env_type}/)
{
     # Do something
}
```

The `m//` match operator binds automatically to `$_`.  There is no need to bind it explicitly.

Comment: With, or without `m/` it is pretty much the same thing.